# Add a "Entry" widget with a button above said button in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-button

I'm fairly new to tkinter and I need to make a button that adds a entry widget in the row above the same button, is it possible?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
playerFrame = Frame(root)

#Players' numbers and names / Numeros e nomes dos jogadores
pnum1 = Label(playerFrame, text="1").grid(column=0, row=0)
pnum2 = Label(playerFrame, text="2").grid(column=0, row=1)
pnum3 = Label(playerFrame, text="3").grid(column=0, row=2)
pnum4 = Label(playerFrame, text="4").grid(column=0, row=3)
pnum5 = Label(playerFrame, text="5").grid(column=0, row=4)
pnum6 = Label(playerFrame, text="6").grid(column=0, row=5)
pnum7 = Label(playerFrame, text="7").grid(column=0, row=6)

player1 = Entry(playerFrame).grid(column=1, row=0)
player2 = Entry(playerFrame).grid(column=1, row=1)
player3 = Entry(playerFrame).grid(column=1, row=2)
player4 = Entry(playerFrame).grid(column=1, row=3)
player5 = Entry(playerFrame).grid(column=1, row=4)
player6 = Entry(playerFrame).grid(column=1, row=5)
player7 = Entry(playerFrame).grid(column=1, row=6)

#Function for the addPlayer button / Função para o botão addPlayer
def AddPlayer():
    pass
#Button to add more players / Botão para adicionar mais jogadores
addPlayer = Button(playerFrame, text="Add player / Adicionar jogador").grid(column=1, row=7)

playerFrame.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW)

root.mainloop()
```

I need the button to go down and add the entry line above it

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You have complete control of putting widgets above, below, or to the side of other widgets. All of the features to do so are documented in many places. Can you add a [mcve] that illustrates the problem you're having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grid_info()` to get the grid information of `addPlayer` button and use this information to move the button one row below and create `Label` and `Entry` in the current row of the button:

```py
#Function for the addPlayer button / Função para o botão addPlayer
def AddPlayer():
    # get the row from grid information of the "addPlayer" button
    info = addPlayer.grid_info()
    row = info['row']
    # move "addPlayer" button to next row
    info['row'] = row + 1
    addPlayer.grid(**info)
    # create label and entry in current row
    Label(playerFrame, text=row+1).grid(row=row, column=0)
    Entry(playerFrame).grid(row=row, column=1)

#Button to add more players / Botão para adicionar mais jogadores
addPlayer = Button(playerFrame, text="Add player / Adicionar jogador", command=AddPlayer)
addPlayer.grid(column=1, row=7)
```

Comment: I tried this but I got this error`Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\pedro\Documents\jobs\Analista\teste.py", line 26, in AddPlayer
    info = addPlayer.grid_info('row')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'grid_info'`

Comment: Did you split the line `addPlayer = Button(...).grid(...)` into two lines like in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Possible Solution:

```
def AddPlayer():
    new_entry = Entry(playerFrame).grid(column=1, row=) # Figure out a way to make the row number increase

#Button to add more players / Botão para adicionar mais jogadores

addPlayer = Button(playerFrame, text="Add player / Adicionar jogador", command=AddPlayer).grid(column=1, row=7)
```